# Create firewalld rule

Tags: ssh, iptables, firewalld

I have this code that I've been using for years (works fine) which takes external requests coming to the server at the port 9944 and redirects those requests internally to localhost on port 9922.

For compliance, I cant use the code below anymore. I have to use `firewalld` to accomplish that. Do you have any idea how can I do this?

```
ssh -L 0.0.0.0:9944:localhost:9922 localhost -N
```

Thank you.

Comment: You want to forward port 9944 on your local machine to port 9922 on the server? I believe you could do this with a firewall rule on your local machine, but that would only work if port 9922 is open to the world on the server, and I assume it isn't because if it were, there would be no need for the tunnel in the first place. Are you looking for a firewall rule to put on the server that only allows your local computer to access that port? in my opinion you've already got a great solution

Comment: Redirecting to localhost (eg 127.0.0.1) rather than to $HOST (eg: 192.0.2.2) is harder than it appears: it probably also involves [`route_localnet`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.rst?h=v6.1#n1549)

Comment: I still cant find a way to do this using firewalld. Unbelievable